# Link custom post type to parent page and show in slug / breadcrumb

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, breadcrumb

I am using the Custom Post Type UI plugin to add custom post types to our website. We now created a CPT called IPDC.

For this custom post type, we would like to have the option to link every IPDC page to a parent page, the parent page being a default Wordpress page. I guess I could do this by adding a custom field, but how do I manage the slug and breadcrumb in that case?

> For example. The IPDC page 'Page B' is linked to default page 'Parent A'. In that case, the slug  should be ***/parent-a/page-b.

Also, we are using the Yoast Plugin, so our new slug structure should be shown there as well.

Can anyone suggest which direction to go in order to implement this?

Thank you

Comment: For the breadcrumbs it would depend entirely on which theme/plugin was used to create the breadcrumbs. You're using Yoast so if you're using that for breadcrumbs then the solution would be specific to that plugin. That makes it off topic here so you'll need to consult the Yoast documentation/support.

Comment: Via custom code in functions.php I was able to give the CPT a parent page, and got the breadcrumbs working as well. The only thing left is rewriting the permalink so the path of the parent page is added in the URL.

I found this code, but I am not sure if we can get the parent page slug (ex. via get_page_uri) this way. 

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse247328_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse247328_register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( $post_type === 'ipdc' ) { $path = get_page_uri($_POST); $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $path; } return $args; }